# Windows: open a named document

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to extend an existing app called [Drax](http://drax.codeplex.com/) which edits the metadata of MP4 movie files..  I want to be able to drag-n-drop files onto it, which it does not support.  I've gotten far enough to be able to decode the "clipboard" data when it is dropped, and filter to accept only the file (extensions) that I can handle.  ([Like so](https://github.com/arantius/drax/compare/master...dragdrop) but I know next to no winapi/C++ so it's all cargo-culted.)

But now I want to trigger opening the document, whose (file) name I have in a TCHAR.  And I'm stuck.  How do I trigger the same sort of action the File>Open dialog would, when I know the name of the file from a drag/drop operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, the File -> Open dialog does not do *anything* but allow the user to choose a file name. It then returns this file name to you, the programmer, to do something with.

But, in this case, you're modifying an existing application, so that code has already been written. To find it, you need to search for the method(s) that display the File -> Open dialog. See what they do with the file name(s) returned by the Open dialog.

All the logic for opening the file is very likely to be crammed into the same method as the one that displays the File -> Open dialog. If so, what I would do is refactor the code, so that you have a separate method like

```
void OpenFile(CString pszFileName, /* other important parameters */)
{
    // ...
}
```

that handles opening the file, specified by a string containing its full path. You will call this method once you get the file name from the File -> Open dialog, and *also* from elsewhere, like after you get the file name from a drag-drop operation.

Comment: As in the linked repository: https://github.com/arantius/drax/blob/dragdrop/drax/Application.cpp#L39 AFAICT there's a default OnFileOpen implementation (that identifier appears nowhere else in the code) wired up with BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP?

Comment: The default `OnFileOpen` implementation calls `CWinApp::OpenDocumentFile` once it has the file name to open (documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/11861byt.aspx)). So you can call the same method. Do check first that it has not been overridden in the derived Application class. If so, call the derived method. @aran